# JQUERY: How to change the input value by clicking a button with a generic JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

I'm not an expert in JQuery but I'm trying to get a value from a button - when the user click a button and the input field will change the value.

But, I can have many buttons.. (In same cases, more than 100) for this reason I want to know if it's possible to get the value from the clicked button with a "generic" JQuery - to avoid a big JQuery with a `$('#answer').val()` for each button..

https://jsfiddle.net/Ldy01wb2/1/

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id ='one' value="A">
<input type="button" id ='two' value="B">
<br><br>
Hidden: <input type="text" id="answer" value="">
```

JQUERY: (what I want)

```
$(':button').click(function(){
    $('#answer').val = $(':button').val ;
});
```

JQUERY: (works.. but if I have 100, I need 100 functions.. and I'm trying to get a generic solution for all buttons)

```
$('#one').click(function(){
    $('#answer').val("A") ;
});

$('#two').click(function(){
    $('#answer').val("B") ;
});
```

Comment: Add a class to the button say` class="mybutton"`  then  in jquery do  `jQuery(".mybutton").click(function(){  var buttonVal = jQuery(this).val()   });`

Comment: your question doesn't show how exactly your HTML looks like, from the question I see that you have questions page with a form, I would suggest that you use radio button for such a thing also that will reduce the amount of data that you handle using `hidden` text field.

Comment: @root I need a "mobile" solution - I opted for a button - and not a radio or other component - because with a button the user only have to do "1-click" - and go to the next page. With a Radio - the user need to do 2 clicks - and for a long list (with 100 options) -  the user need to find the "next button" on bottom too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(this)` gives you the button you clicked on, I guess that's all you need.

```js
$('[type=button]').click(function(){
    $('#answer').val($(this).val()) ;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id='one' value="A">
<input type="button" id='two' value="B">
<br><br>
Hidden: <input type="text" id="answer" value="">
```

Comment: What if there are other buttons exists on the same page. I this class would be a better option or you can do check `[type=button]` inside a specific element using id

Comment: Exactly, if you need to be more specific then use classes to limit this to only the buttons you need. But based on the question OP want's to target all buttons.

Comment: @cloned first of all, tks for your precious time to share and help me. I upvote your solution - and works fine to me too! :D tks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Please give a class to the button and get the value based on class

```js
$('.mybutton').click(function(){
    $('#myInput').val($(this).val()) ;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="mybutton" id='one' value="A">
<input type="button" class="mybutton" id='two' value="B">
<br><br>
Hidden: <input type="text" id="myInput" value="">
```

Comment: first of all, tks for your precious time to share and help me. I upvote your solution - and works fine to me too! :D tks a lot!

Comment: of course, I just need to wait for the min. time to accept ;D

Answer (score 0):

```
$("button, input[type='button']").click(function(){
    $('#answer').val(this.val()) ;
});
```

Please check here for more information https://api.jquery.com/button-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Use a class to query instead of ID.

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    $('#answer').val($(this).val());
});
```

You can also use `$('input:button').click(function()` without using a class